# Scroll to previous place after postback in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm implementing cross-browser web apllication with ASP.NET WebForms. So, I have dynamically created table, where each cell is custom user control inherited from `TableCell`. In my controls there is `asp:Panel` with several textboxs. Because of dynamic creation of table, it can be different width. When I change text in one of textboxes, `TextChanged` event fires and page refreshing. But because of it scroll jump to top. How can I scroll page to previous position?

I've tried `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true` but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to assist you in this endeavor. A couple years ago I ran into the same problem and was able to remedy using JavaScript to do the scrolling after post back.

Here is an article for you to read: http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/

Essentially you will be adding events and parameters to your page requests which will do the lifting for you.

Code from the article:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
      // It is important to place this JavaScript code after ScriptManager1
      var xPos, yPos;
      var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

      function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if ($get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>') != null) {
          // Get X and Y positions of scrollbar before the partial postback
          xPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollLeft;
          yPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
        }
     }

     function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         if ($get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>') != null) {
           // Set X and Y positions back to the scrollbar
           // after partial postback
           $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollLeft = xPos;
           $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').scrollTop = yPos;
         }
     }

     prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
     prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
 </script>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="300">
        <%-- Some stuff which would cause a partial postback goes here --%>
     </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```